# Blazor, Razor Library, npm and webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, razor, blazor-webassembly

Hopefully I can explain this clearly.
I have a Blazor WASM project that is referencing a Razor library (everything fine here).
The Razor library compiles a JavaScript bundle using webpack (everything works here).
One of the components I am trying to create has one simple function that returns the revesion of a package (threejs) as a string.

Now the problem.
When I try to call the function from the Blazor project I keep receiving that the function does not exist.

Error

[image: 1]

- index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Atom.Web.Client</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Atom.Web.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="./_content/Atom.Web.Viewer.Components/js/atom.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

- Webpack config

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/js'),
        filename: "atom.bundle.js",
        library: "Atom"
    }
};
```

- the component code

```cs
private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

        public ThreeViewer(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./_content/Atom.Web.Viewer.Components/js/atom.bundle.js").AsTask());
        }


        public async ValueTask<string> GetRevision()
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            var rev =  await module.InvokeAsync<string>("Atom.GetCurrentThreeRevision");
            return rev;
        }
```

- the Program.cs

```cs
using Atom.Web.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Atom.Web.Viewer.Components;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped<ThreeViewer>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

- the Index.razor

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
@inject ThreeViewer threeViewer;
@page "/"
@using Newtonsoft.Json

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@if(revisionMessage != string.Empty)
{
    <h1>@revisionMessage</h1>
}

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    string revisionMessage = string.Empty;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        revisionMessage = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("Atom.GetCurrentThreeRevision");
        var rev = await threeViewer.GetRevision();
    }

}
```

The interesting part is, if I call the function directly using jsruntime `revisionMessage` it works fine, if I try to call it from the component library, it doesn't.

Anyone can be of any help?

Comment: Ok I have figured this out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured this out myself.
I had to remove dynamic loading of the library within the Razor component and assume that this library will be loaded in the main Blazor app.

```cs
public async Task<string> GetRevision()
        {
            return await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("Atom.GetCurrentThreeRevision");
        }

        public async Task<Scene> InitiateScene()
        {
            string text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new { Scene, ViewerSettings, Camera, OrbitControls }, SerializationHelper.GetSerializerSettings());
            return await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Scene>("Atom.InitiateScene");
        }
```

everything else remains the same basically.